# Is there any example of a US VFR sectional chart containing both a reference to "Class E" airspace, and to older terminology for the same airspace?

Tags: aeronautical-charts

Is there any example of a US VFR sectional chart whose legend describes the  airspace depicted by the thin dashed magenta line both as "Class E"  or "Class E airspace", and also with the older terminology "Control Zone at airport without control tower and Control Zone extension without communications requirement", or similar?

Based on old sectional charts I've looked at-- and new batches of chart updates become effective on a 28-day cycle-- this would have happened no sooner than 28 days after August 19 1993, and no later than 28 days before November 11 1993.  So it appears that the only possible dates for such a situation are Sept 16 1993 or October 14 1993.

In answering this question please disregard any reference to non-US airspace on the legends of US VFR sectional aeronautical charts.

Note that this related answer to a related question [Re old (1992) US VFR sectional charts-- when was the thin dashed magenta line first used?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/56674/re-old-1992-us-vfr-sectional-charts-when-was-the-thin-dashed-magenta-line-fi/56697#56697) clearly describes an INTENTION to have dual legends (including the old and new airspace terminology) on aeronautical charts between October 15 1992 and mid 1994.  But was this ever actually done on US VFR sectional charts?  Checking charts with effective dates of Sept 16 1993 and Oct 14 1993 should settle the issue.

Comment: Sectionals are updated every 6 months, not every 28 days.

Comment: Yes any given sectional is updated every 6 months, but it appears that every 28 days another batch of charts--i.e. another batch of locations-- is being revised.  This was pointed out in an answer to another related question.

Comment: I've edited the question to try to avoid confusion-- I can see why original wording would have been confusing.

Comment: First sentence second paragraph should go "...-- and considering that new batches of chart updates..."

Comment: Second-to-last sentence really should read "But-- specifically in relation to airspace marked by the thin dashed magenta line-- was this ever actually done on US VFR sectional charts?"